# How can an HTTP request continue after cancellation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I use .NET 6.0 for an API.

When the user goes to a different page on our (react) webapp it automatically cancels the ongoing HTTP requests. What I see on my end (.NET API) is a System.OperationCanceledException and then the processing completely stops.

This is annoying because if the user creates an item on the webapp but switches to another page before the API got time to save the data to our database we get problems.
I tried to reproduce this locally but after I cancel the request in postman I can see the exception in the console but the execution seems to continue. The debugger does hit breakpoints after the request was cancelled.

Why is the behavior different? And how can I change this into a "fire and forget" request?
I did some research online but I could only find people asking about cancelling things instead of NOT cancelling things.

I'm not even sure "fire and forget" is the right term, since we don need a response if the user stays on the same page.

And we looked into changing this on the frontend side, but this doesn't really matter since the user can simply close their browser.

Comment: HTTP requests can't be cancelled. HTTP is stateless and has no mechanism to tell the server to "cancel" processing an HTTP request. Clients can only stop waiting for a response and possibly close the connection used *for that HTTP request*. You get `OperationCanceledException` because the browser connection was interrupted while the server was reading from or writing to it. If the server wasn't trying to use the connection, it wouldn't see the cancellation. Most likely POSTMAN simply stops waiting when you stop a request, it doesn't close the connection

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely can create a fire-and-forget function (It already is) , however not waiting for the response comes with a few problems:

1: Any error that happens to that fire and forget call, is basically lost to you, if you for example attempt to log the error to a persistence layer, and said layer fails, you can't tell the user that the error happened.

2: If the user is able to lose a request by leaving the page, why not just warn the user that they are about to leave an active process that hasn't finished yet, and will cancel it, instead?
This at least imitates what is actually happening.
Implement a cancellation token for an async call.

3: If you ever wish to actually tell the user that the request is done, that won't really be an option, you would have to create a page, where the user can go back to.
Lets say you put the request into a queue (like rabbitmq or kafka) then the user would have to go to a page with a UI that can show processes being processed by this queue system, or whatever system you choose to use.

How do you make a user aware that this is even an option?

The fire and forget solution will be very user un-friendly.

Comment: Those are good points, I'll look further into this, thanks!